# Sharepoint Framework/PnP-JS/React : How to set a Class Property Value from a callback function

Tags: sharepoint-framework, pnp-js-core, react

```
import { Web } from "sp-pnp-js";
    import pnp from "sp-pnp-js";


interface ISPVehicule {
  Title: string;
  Marque: string;
  Modele: string;
  Vitesse: string;
  Poid: string;
}


export default class ReactPnP extends React.Component<IReactPnPProps, {}> {

  private vehiculeList:  ISPVehicule[];
  private web;

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.web = new Web(this.props.contextUrl);

    this.web.lists.getByTitle("Voitures").items.get()
      .then((vehicules: ISPVehicule[]) => 
      {
        this.vehiculeList = vehicules
      });

      console.log("vehicule : " + this.vehiculeList);
  }
....
```

I would like to store the Get Method result in the VehiculeList property. However, it does not work the way I have done it.
In fact, I am getting  this error message:

> "vehicule : undefined"

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Eventually, I would like to use this property to display its content by injecting the following code in the Render Method :

```
{this.vehiculeList.map((vehicule) =>{ return (<div>{vehicule.Title}</div>); } )}.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using state instead of private property. When property is changed React does not know about it and does not re-render the component. When the state is changed in `componentDidMount` it will re-rende the component.

```
import { Web } from "sp-pnp-js";
import pnp from "sp-pnp-js";

interface ISPVehicule {
  Title: string;
  Marque: string;
  Modele: string;
  Vitesse: string;
  Poid: string;
}

interface IState {
  vehiculeList: ISPVehicule[];
}

// Define some state object instead of empty object {}
export default class ReactPnP extends React.Component<IReactPnPProps, IState> {
  private web;

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.vehiculeList.map((vehicule: ISPVehicule) =>
          <div>{vehicule.Title}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  // Http call when component mounts
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.web = new Web(this.props.contextUrl);

    this.web.lists.getByTitle("Voitures").items.get()
      .then((vehicules: ISPVehicule[]) => {
        // Use callback for reading the value from this.state
        this.setState({ vehiculeList: vehicules }, () => {
          console.log("vehicule : " + this.state.vehiculeList);
        });
      });
  }
}
```